# Get the last word of a part of a varchar (LEFT/RIGHT)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

What is the correct way to get the last word of a part of a varchar?

```
DECLARE @desc varchar(100)
SET @desc='EXCHANGEUNIT P1i / SILVERBLACK/ CYRILLIC'

SELECT RTRIM(LEFT(@desc, CHARINDEX('/', @desc) - 1))
```

This returns: `EXCHANGEUNIT P1i`

I need to get only `P1i` with the query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no "correct" way. is your data always like this:"ValueSpaceValueSpaceSlashSpaceValueSpaceSlashSpaceValue"

Comment: No. I would be glad if someone could show the fastest way to get `P1i` from `EXCHANGEUNIT P1i / SILVERBLACK/ CYRILLIC`. Actually there is no guarantee that there is a `/` or trailing space or space at all. But that is part of the `where` condition of the query. I've reduced the query to the issue of separating a varchar value to another varchar value on strictly specified conditions.

Comment: @MarkBannister gives an answer that works for your example data.  In there event that not all data conforms to that format, please could you include example of all possible corner cases?  And/or hard and fast rules about the naturue of the string being parsed?

Comment: @Dems: Marks answer works for me. I cannot get it working for all data, i have no bearing on it since it's external data. One other example would be `W200I_E/Swap unit/Black`. How to get the `W200I` out of it. I'm afraid that the more i handle those special cases, the more buggy the query will be, because it'll be too generous(i cannot know if the `_` is part of the modelname `W200I` or not).

Comment: @TimSchmelter - Any function can only follow a set of rules.  Either you need to supply every possible format of data (so that we can infer the rules), or you need to describe the rules and we can translate them into SQL.  If there is no fixed pattern to the behaviour of your data, there is no fixed SQL query that can parse it.

Comment: @Dems: I realized that @Mark's answer may be correct, but does not work for the "normal" cases where there is no ` ` at all in the first part before `/`(f.e. `W200I_E/Swap unit/Black` mentioned in my last comment).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a combination of REVERSE, LEFT and CHARINDEX - like so:

```
DECLARE @desc varchar(100)
SET @desc='EXCHANGEUNIT P1i / SILVERBLACK/ CYRILLIC'
SET @subdesc=RTRIM(LEFT(@desc, CHARINDEX('/', @desc) - 1))


SELECT REVERSE( LEFT( REVERSE(@subdesc), CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(@subdesc))-1 ) )
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what i was looking for. Looks weird if i combine both and add that to a group by clause of another query. But that is the way to go.

Comment: @Dems: I realized that this does not work for the "normal" cases where there is no blank at all in the first part before `/`(f.e. `W200I_E/Swap unit/Black`).  How to change the query between my approach and yours according to the existence of a whitespace before `/`? The only i can ensure is that the is a `/`, because that is part of the `where` clause as well.

Comment: @Tim: The problem is, you still haven't properly defined the problem to be solved; you have only included a single example. So we don't know whether there will always be at least one word before the first `/`, whether there will always be a space immediately before the first `/`, whether you want to use any other characters as word separators (such as commas, colons, tabs,...), etc.

Comment: I wanted to reduce my question as much as possible, otherwise it would have been difficult to understand what actually my problem is. I've mentioned that immediately after gbn has asked, there is no guarantee at all. It is only a try to link two tables via nullable foreign-key. The only strong rule i can see is that there mostly is a `/` as separator and there *might be* trailing blanks to discard unnecessary words from the first part. So the `/`-Rule is strong, because it's part of the where-clause, that there must be a `/` before joining both tables whereas the `blank`-Rule is not.

Comment: @Tim: In the same comment where you said that there was no guarantee, you also said that you had "reduced the query to the issue of separating a varchar value to another varchar value on strictly specified conditions". The point that gbn, Dems and I have all made (repeatedly) is that **you have not strictly specified those conditions**.

Comment: Mybe i better create a new question for the `invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function` because both questions are related only indirectly and you've already answered my question how to find the **last word** of the **first part** of a string. Conditions were strictly specified as:  1.) first part=`RTRIM(LEFT(@desc, CHARINDEX('/', @desc) - 1))` 2.) last word=separated by a whitespace.

Comment: If you are interested, [this is the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8446044/ternary-operator-in-sql-invalid-length-parameter-passed-to-the-left-or-substri).