# Ternary operator in SQL? "invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function"

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

Sorry for this misleading subject, i didn't know how to word better.
Because i'm mainly a software-developer, the ternary operator comes to my mind with my following problem.

I need to find the most robust way to link two tables via nullable foreign-key(`modModel` and `tabSparePart`). The only similarity between both is the model's name and the sparepart's description(the `tabSparePart` is an external table from customer that is imported automatically, so it's not my responsibility and i cannot change the data).

Consider the following sparepart-names:

```
W200I_E/Swap
EXCHANGEUNIT P1i / SILVERBLACK/ CYRILLIC
```

The modelnames that i want to find are `P1i` and `W200I_E`. 
So there is only one strong rule that i can ensure in the `where-clause`:

- there must be a separator `/` and the relevant part is the first one.

Here is the sample data:

```
Create table #temp(Partname varchar(100))
INSERT INTO #temp
    SELECT 'EXCHANGEUNIT P1i / SILVERBLACK/ CYRILLIC' UNION ALL SELECT 'W200I_E/Swap unit/Black'
```

I would have been finished with following query:

```
SELECT RTRIM(LEFT(Partname, CHARINDEX('/', Partname) - 1)) AS UNIT
FROM #temp
WHERE CHARINDEX('/', Partname) > 0
```

... what returns:

```
EXCHANGEUNIT P1i
W200I_E
```

But i need `P1i`. So i need a way to handle also the case that the first part is separated by whitespaces. In that case i need to select the last word, but only if it **is** separated at all.

I'm getting a `"invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function"`-error with following query:

```
SELECT REVERSE( LEFT( REVERSE(RTRIM(LEFT(Partname, CHARINDEX('/', Partname) - 1)))
    , CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(RTRIM(LEFT(Partname, CHARINDEX('/', Partname) - 1))))-1 ))
    AS Unit
FROM #temp
WHERE CHARINDEX('/', Partname) > 0
```

This would work without the second record that has no whitespace. If i would also ensure that the first part contains a whitespace, i would discard valid records.

To cut a long story short, I need to find a way to combine both ways according to the existence of separators.

PS: This has arisen from: [Get the last word of a part of a varchar (LEFT/RIGHT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8444175/get-the-last-word-of-a-part-of-a-varchar-left-right)

---

If anybody is interested, this is the complete (working) stored-procedure. I'm sure i've never used such a strange `JOIN`:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[UpdateModelSparePart](@updateCount int output)
with execute as Owner
AS
    BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    UPDATE modModel SET fiSparePart=ModelPart.idSparePart
        FROM modModel INNER JOIN 
        (
          SELECT m.idModel
                ,m.ModelName
                ,sp.idSparePart
                ,sp.Price
                ,Row_Number()Over(Partition By idModel ORDER BY Price DESC)as ModelPrice
          FROM modModel AS m INNER JOIN tabSparePart AS sp 
            ON m.ModelName = CASE 
                WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(RTRIM(LEFT(sp.SparePartDescription, CHARINDEX('/', sp.SparePartDescription) - 1))))  > 0 THEN
                    REVERSE(  LEFT( REVERSE(RTRIM(LEFT(sp.SparePartDescription, CHARINDEX('/', sp.SparePartDescription) - 1)))
                    ,CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(RTRIM(LEFT(sp.SparePartDescription, CHARINDEX('/', sp.SparePartDescription) - 1))))-1 ))
                ELSE
                    RTRIM(LEFT(sp.SparePartDescription, CHARINDEX('/', sp.SparePartDescription) - 1))
                END
          WHERE (CHARINDEX('/', sp.SparePartDescription) > 0)
          GROUP BY idModel,ModelName,idSparePart,Price
        )As ModelPart
    ON ModelPart.idModel=modModel.idModel
    Where ModelPrice=1

    SET @updateCount = @@ROWCOUNT;

    COMMIT TRANSACTION

END
```

Comment: Where does this data originate? It should be split before being put into the data where it is stored as components

Comment: The data is from a customer, i cannot influence the format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem:

```
SELECT 'Unit' =
    CASE 
    WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(RTRIM(LEFT(Partname, CHARINDEX('/', Partname) - 1))))  > 0 THEN
         REVERSE( LEFT( REVERSE(RTRIM(LEFT(Partname, CHARINDEX('/', Partname) - 1)))
        ,CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(RTRIM(LEFT(Partname, CHARINDEX('/', Partname) - 1))))-1 ))
    ELSE 
        RTRIM(LEFT(Partname, CHARINDEX('/', Partname) - 1))
    END
FROM #temp
WHERE CHARINDEX('/', Partname) > 0
```

Ugly but working fine.

Answer (score 2):

A more concise version.

```
SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(Rev, 0, CHARINDEX(' ', Rev))) AS Unit
FROM   #temp
       CROSS APPLY ( 
        SELECT REVERSE(RTRIM(LEFT(Partname, CHARINDEX('/', Partname) - 1))) + ' '
        ) T(Rev)
WHERE  CHARINDEX('/', Partname) > 0
```

Comment: Thanks. But it causes a `"RTRIM" is not a recognized table hints option. If it is intended as a parameter to a table-valued function, ensure that your database compatibility mode is set to 90` error.

Comment: @Tim - It looks like I managed to delete the first 4 letters of `SELECT` when trying to fit it into the code block nicely. Fixed!