# How to get the second last word in a string?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a string like below, and I need to get 10472314 in it. It is the last word but one in this case. Can you let me know how to get it in PL/SQL block? Any string function?

```
processed "SCOTT"."PRINCE05"                         10472314 rows
```

Comment: If you are honest you will admit that, if you read the question again (and pretend you don't know what it is about) it doesn't even make sense to YOU. How is it supposed to make sense to US? What do you mean by "the number of rows in a string"? And what does that have to do with "How to get **specific word** in string" (YOUR title)?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I modified the title and statements. Sorry for confusing you.

Comment: OK - I assume you mean the "second to last" word (meaning, second word from the end of the string). Is that what you always need, the second-to-last word in a string? And how do you define "word" - anything separated by spaces (or by spaces, tabs, newlines - what is generally called "whitespace")?

Comment: You might want to check this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8444175/get-the-last-word-of-a-part-of-a-varchar-left-right

Comment: Are you really just getting the number of rows processed from within PL/SQL? You should be able to get that via a cursor variable...

Comment: The functions you need are SUBSTRING and INSTR

Comment: Good point. I am trying to make it with those functions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we use a '-1' magic option in INSTR then we can search the string in reverse order. By doing that, I believe we can find the last word but one like below.
It looks dirty but it just works for me.

```
SELECT SUBSTR( name, INSTR( name, ' ', -1 , 2 ) + 1 , INSTR( name, ' ', -1 , 1 ) - INSTR( name, ' ', -1 , 2 ) ) 
FROM prince_test;

INSTR( name, ' ', -1 , 2 ) + 1  ==> the second occurrence of SPACE
INSTR( name, ' ', -1 , 1 ) - INSTR( name, ' ', -1 , 2 )  ==> position gap between the first occurrence and the second.
```

Answer (score 3):

The set of digits before the word 'rows' at the end of the string:

```
regexp_replace(text, '^(.+ )([0-9]+)( rows)$', '\2')
```

The third word:

```
regexp_substr(text, '\S+', 1, 3)
```

The second last word (the *n*th word where *n* = the number of words -1):

```
regexp_substr(text, '\S+', 1, regexp_count(text,'\S+') -1)
```

If you are processing a significant number of rows then the regex functions can be slow. The trade-off you have to make is between the expressiveness of regular expressions and the performance of plain `substr` and `instr`. Personally I prefer regexes unless there is a clear performance issue.

Answer (score 1):

This gets you the last TWO words in a string and then shows you the first word of those two words which will always be the second-last word:

SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(, " ", -2), ' ', 1)